# Xamarin - How to add endpoints automatically to Amazon SNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, xamarin, amazon-sns

I am working on an Android and iOS app using Xamaring and I want to send push notifications via Amazon SNS.

But I don't know how it works exactly. In my case, the app is a kind of a chat, where there is a plenty of users sending messages to each other.

I wonder how to register automatically the device's token to the Amazon SNS.
Who register the token? The backend or the application side?

And how would I do that?

Note: I'm using NodeJS as backend.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you've found it on your own, but the SNS documentation is pretty solid on this front. Work your way through all the docs before you begin. With a Node backend you'll be using the AWS JS library, which is also well documented.

Start here: [AWS SNS Mobile Push](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SNSMobilePush.html)

then read about [token management](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/mobile-token-management-with-amazon-sns/)